# Elementary Set Theory: Bijections and the Cartesian Pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help proving that the following map is a bijection:

Suppose $S = \{(x,y)∈R^2 : x^2 +y^2=1\}$. Show that the following function is a bijection

$$F:[0,2π)→S:θ↦(\cosθ,\sinθ)$$

I'm not entirely sure how to start this off

Comment: If $(\cos\theta_1,\sin\theta_1)=(\cos\theta_2,\sin\theta_2)$ and $0\leq \theta_1<2\pi$ and $0\leq \theta_2<2\pi$, does that imply that $\theta_1=\theta_2$?  If $(x,y)\in S$, does there exist some $\theta$ for which $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are two standard ways to show a function $f: A\to B$ is a bijection.

Approach 1: Show that $f$ is (1) an injection and (2) a surjection.

Approach 2: Produce the inverse $f^{-1}$ of $f$, in other words, a function $g: B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_{A}$ and $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_{B}$.